# Combine F# async and maybe computation expression

Tags: asynchronous, f#, monads, monad-transformers, computation-expression

Say i want to return an `Option` while in an `async` workflow:

```fs
let run = 
    async {
        let! x = doAsyncThing
        let! y = doNextAsyncThing x
        match y with
        | None -> return None
        | Some z -> return Some <| f z
    }
```

Ideally I would use the maybe computation expression from FSharpx at the same time as async to avoid doing the `match`. I could make a custom builder, but is there a way to generically combine two computation expressions? It might look something like this:

```
let run = 
    async {
        let! x = doAsyncThing
        let! y = doNextAsyncThing x
        return! f y
    }
```

Comment: I think you're asking for what Haskell calls "monad transformers", in which case the short answer is "no". There's no generic way to combine them, unfortunately. In Haskell there's a transformer version of each standard monad that you can then graft onto others, but I'm not sure it's even possible to define those in F#'s type system...

Comment: You might be interested in an approved proposed feature called [match!](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/572) (as in "match-bang"): it's a "let!" followed by a "match". I've wanted something to do what you're talking about for a little while now, and I've been working on getting it implemented into F#

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Typically in F# instead of using generic workflows you define the workflow by hand, or use one that is ready available as in your case `async` and `maybe` but if you want to use them combined you will need to code a specific workflow combination by hand.

Alternatively you can use [F#+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharpPlus/) which is a project that provides generic workflows for monads, in that case it will be automatically derived for you, here's a working example, using your workflow and then using `OptionT` which is a monad transformer:

```
#r "nuget: FSharpPlus, 1.2"

open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

let doAsyncThing = async {return System.DateTime.Now}
let doNextAsyncThing (x:System.DateTime) = async {
    let m = x.Millisecond  
    return (if m < 500 then Some m else None)}
let f x = 2 * x

// then you can use Async<_> (same as your code)
let run = monad {
    let! x = doAsyncThing
    let! y = doNextAsyncThing x
    match y with
    | None   -> return None
    | Some z -> return Some <| f z}

let res = Async.RunSynchronously run

// or you can use OptionT<Async<_>> (monad transformer)

let run' = monad {
    let! x = lift doAsyncThing
    let! y = OptionT (doNextAsyncThing x)
    return f y}

let res' = run' |> OptionT.run |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The first function has to be 'lifted' into the other monad, because it only deals with `Async` (not with `Option`), the second function deals with both so it only needs to be 'packed' into our `OptionT` DU.

As you can see both workflows are derived automatically, the one you had (the async workflow) and the one you want.

For more information about this approach read about [Monad Transformers](https://www.google.ch/#q=monad+transformers).

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to do so is to use [Option module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370544.aspx):

```
let run = 
    async {
        let! x = doAsyncThing
        let! y = doNextAsyncThing x
        return Option.map f y
    }
```

I suppose you don't have to deal with `option` in context of `async` so often. FSharpx also provides many more [high-order functions](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L83) for `option` type. Most of the cases, I think using them is enough.

To get the feeling of using these functions, please take a look at this [nice article](http://missingfaktor.blogspot.dk/2012/02/f-option-cheat-sheet.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
type MaybeMonad() = 
    member __.Bind(x, f) = 
        match x with
        | Some v -> f v
        | None -> None
    member __.Return(x) = 
        Some x

let maybe = MaybeMonad()

let run = async {
    let! x = doAsyncThing
    let! y = doNextAsyncThing x
    return maybe {
        let! y_val = y
        return f y_val
    }
}
```

just use f# Computation expressions inside.