# How to update the state with async requests using the state monad?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, f#, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm doing an app using F# and I wonder if I could **a)** Keep the state under the State computation expression (using FSharpx's implementation) and **b)** be able to modify the state asynchronously (handling the user's input).

I believe I know how to handle each problem separately; either:

- Keep the state in mutable variables and use async & MailboxProcessor to receive async requests to modify the state
- Use the state computation expression but not being able to process the user input.

How could I use both the state and the async computation expressions in FSharp or Haskell?

Comment: How do you want the two to interact? For instance you could use an intermediary to store the asynchronous requests and then have a portion of the state computation expression pull from that the perform the actual update, but that would involve stalling the resultant updates until the state computation checks. I don't believe there is an alternative though without breaking a lot of guarantees about the state computation (since you no longer know when it can change, and can no longer simply stream it through your process as a single immutable value).

Comment: I'm finishing my first attempt. When I finish it, I'll post it as an edit to let you know my requirements. Then, any improvement would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically there are 2 approaches to combine monads: use monad transformers or create a custom monad by hand which combines both monads.

Since there are no native type classes in F# you usually end up with the latter solution, but you can use [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) to combine Async and State a-la Haskell and get the desired computation expression.

Here's an example translated from Haskell:

```ml
#r @"FSharpPlus.dll"

open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

let print x = async {printfn "%A" x}

#nowarn "0025" // Incomplete pattern match, list is assumed not to be empty.
let code  =
    let inline io (x: Async<_>)  : StateT<_,Async<_>> = liftAsync x
    let pop  = monad {
        let! (x::xs) = get
        do! put xs
        return x}
    monad {
        let! x = pop
        do! io <| print x
        let! y = pop
        do! io <| print y
        return () }

let main = StateT.run code [1..10] >>= fun _ -> result ()

// try Async.RunSynchronously main
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129277/can-i-use-different-workflows-simultaneously-in-f/19143542#19143542) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376833/combine-f-async-and-maybe-computation-expression/32953319#32953319) related questions.